# Nuxt localtunnel module

Tags: localhost, nuxt.js

Im having a Nuxt.js project where i have installed the fallowing module [@nuxtjs/localtunnel](https://github.com/nuxt-community/modules/tree/master/packages/localtunnel)

I did as instructed where I module in my nuxt.config.js

```
modules: ['@nuxtjs/localtunnel']
```

I run `npm run dev` command, but i can not make an external access.

I try to access at https://localtunnel.me but i get 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a problem with localtunnel or your localtunnel connection, maybe involving SSH. You could run `DEBUG=* npx localtunnel -p 8000` and see if you get an error message.

FWIW, I am currently getting the message `localtunnel:client tunnel server offline: unable to verify the first certificate`, and it is not returning the subdomain.

Comment: Server is down. https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues/264